# Extra "row-level" data in ListView django

Tags: python, django, listview, django-class-based-views

I'm writing my first django app and can't seem to pass "row-level" data to the template through ListView.  Specifically I'm trying to show all Polls and their corresponding Vote information using a PollListView.

Currently I am only able to pass all votes to the template, but would like to pass only the votes that belong to the specific poll.

**models.py**

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Vote(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, unique=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    vote = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default='unset', choices=choices)
```

**views.py**

```
class PollListView(ListView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    context_object_name="poll_list"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PollListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['vote_list'] = Vote.objects.all()
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    url(r'^$', PollListView.as_view(), name="poll-list"),
}
```

**homepage.html**

```
{% for poll in poll_list %}
  {{ poll.title }}
  {% for vote in vote_list %} 
     {{ vote.id }} {{ vote.vote }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Seems like an easy task, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this using class-based views.  Should I be using mixins or extra_context?  Overwrite queryset?  Or should I just used function-based views to solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're asking for all the Votes. You should use `Vote.objects.filter(poll=instance)` I think.

Comment: @RobL I'm not getting an error so much as I'm getting all votes returned to each poll.  So if each poll has 1 vote and I have 3 polls, I'm getting PollA - 3 votes, PollB - 3 votes, PollC - 3 votes.

Comment: @RobL Thank you for the feedback.  I tried your suggestion (Vote.objects.filter(poll=instance) using self.instance but got the following error: 'PollListView' object has no attribute 'instance'

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. @mariodev has it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's gonna work, but you can try the following:

**models.py** (Vote class)

```
poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, related_name="votes", unique=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class PollListView(ListView):
    queryset = Poll.objects.all().prefetch_related('votes')
```

with that you can access related votes:

**template**

```
{% for poll in poll_list %}
  {{ poll.title }}
  {% for vote in poll.votes.all %} 
     {{ vote.id }} {{ vote.vote }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I added the queryset to the ListView.  No error, but the vars weren't available in the template.  Do I need to add a ManyToMany field to Poll for this to work?

Comment: @Darth No, it uses reverse relationships as well. Did you remove `model` attribute from the view?

Comment: I removed the model attribute and no luck.  Do I need to define "vote_set" somewhere?  Should I be overwriting the get_queryset method or is setting the attribute in the class definition sufficient?

Comment: @Darth I've updated my post, try it again with the changes. If that won't work, I'll try it myself..